# Powershell code cannot recognize all excel file(*.xlsm) in current location

Tags: excel, powershell

> I'm currently working on Powershell to handle excel files(*.xlsm).
>      The problem is the code below can only read "test.xlsm".
>      When the name is not test like "this.xlsm" , that code cannot read the file.
>      Any help...?
>      Thanks for your answer in advance :)

```
$destination = "C:\JJ\"

$dirName = Get-ChildItem -Name -Filter *.xlsm
$saveAs = $destination + "new\"

foreach($z in $dirName){
    $excel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excel.visible=$false
    $excel.Displ`ayAlerts=$false
    $book=$excel.Workbooks.Open($destination + $z)
    $sheet=$book.Worksheets.item(1)  
    $sheet.Cells.Item(1,5)="=max(B2:B6)"
    $book.SaveAs($saveAs + $z)
    $excel.Quit()
    $excel=$null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using confusing variable names in your code.. Why call the source path `$destination`??

Anyway, you should use the `-File` switch on your `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to make sure this will only return FileInfo objects, not DirectoryInfo objects aswell. (these are **Objects**, not strings)

Then, there is a better way to construct paths. Use [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7) instead of concatenating things like with `$destination + $z`.

Lastly, I would create the Excel object only once, before the loop and cleanup memory afterwards. Now, you are creating new COM objects in every iteration and never release them from memory.

Below code should do what you intend:

```
$source = "C:\JJ"
$destination = Join-Path -Path $source -ChildPath 'new'

# test if the destination path already exists and if not, create it
if (!(Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
}

# create the Excel COM object outside the loop
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

# get all *.xlsm files inside the source folder
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter '*.xlsm' -File | ForEach-Object {
    # The $_ automatic variable represents 1 FileInfo object in each iteration
    $book  = $excel.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)
    $sheet = $book.Worksheets.item(1)  
    $sheet.Cells.Item(1,5) = "=max(B2:B6)"
    # join the destination path and the file name for output
    $saveAs = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.Name
    $book.SaveAs($saveAs)
    $book.Close()
}

# cleanup Com objects
$excel.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($book)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
$excel = $null
```

Note, If you have PowerShell version below 3.0, the `-File` switch is not available. Instead, then use

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter '*.xlsm' | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..! I corrected for additional functions and it works well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# remove -name to get a directory object instead of a string
$dirName = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xlsm

# you need the file name from the directory object listing
foreach($z in $dirName.name){ ...... }
```

Comment: Thank you for  your advice!